# Simple Rails Calculation Incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I can't figure out why a calculation is wrong.  I'm trying to calculate the percent of time that the user scores over the median score in my Rails app.

controller

```
my_scores_over_median_count = 6
total_scores_over_median = 8
@my_over_median_percent = (my_scores_over_median_count / total_scores_over_median) * 100
```

When I add this to my controller:

```
puts my_scores_over_median_count
puts total_scores_over_median 
puts @my_over_median_percent
```

I get:

```
6 (correct)
8 (correct)
0 (incorrect)
```

Can someone please help me understand why I'm getting `0` instead of `75` ?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

classic integer division problem.  Change it to this and see it work:

```
my_scores_over_median_count = 6.0
total_scores_over_median = 8.0
@my_over_median_percent = (my_scores_over_median_count / total_scores_over_median) * 100
```

Ruby interprets 6 as a 'Fixnum' class, essentially an integer.  We know this by:

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > 6.class
 => Fixnum
```

Dividing any number by a Fixnum causes Ruby to do integer math which means any remainder gets thrown out.  So:

```
1.9.3-p194 :004 > 4 / 5
 => 0 
1.9.3-p194 :005 > 4 / 3
 => 1
```

If you have a variable that is a Fixnum, and you want to convert it to a float to force floating point division, you use the .to_f method:

```
1.9.3-p194 :007 > x = 4
 => 4 
1.9.3-p194 :008 > y = 5
 => 5 
1.9.3-p194 :009 > x / y
 => 0 
1.9.3-p194 :010 > x.to_f / y
 => 0.8
```

Comment: that works!  right now, the scores are counts.  how do i change those so that they work.  for example, i have `my_scores_over_median_count = @my_games.where("my_score > ?", median_score).count`.  thank you

Comment: edited to show how to use the .to_f method force count into a Float